# How do I select this span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This my element that I want to select in jquery

```
.box3 span.info:before{
  content:"15 vacatures";
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 28px 0;

    font-family: 'MaisonNeueMono';
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position:relative;
}
```

I tried this but it just doesn't select it, also doesn't work with just putting ".info":
So how do I select this element?

```
$(".box3 span.info:before").hover(function(){
    $(".box3 h1").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `:before`,it  is just the css part , it is not rendered with element, it is just use to add css before the element.

you just need to write this:

```
$(".box3 span.info").hover(function(){
    $(".box3 h1").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo element `before` is not part of the selector, just leave it out:

```
$(".box3 span.info").hover(function(){
    $(".box3 h1").fadeOut();
});
```

Additionally you may want to separate the style & content insertion like this:

```
.box3 span.info {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 28px 0;

    font-family: 'MaisonNeueMono';
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position:relative;
}

.box3 span.info::before{ 
    content:"15 vacatures";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need psuedo selector here. you need to use:

```
$(".box3 span.info").hover(function(){
  $(this).closest('.box3').find('h1').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select pseudoelements with jQuery as those are not real DOM objects thus are not existing in jQuery context.

That said your `:before` pseudoelement can't be selected with jQuery.

If you need more explanation search on SO, example:
[Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)